# Send an Intent from HTML5 page to the Tasker App to run a profile or task

Tags: html, flash, android-intent, tasker

Let me start off by saying this is for a local web site and a local Android tablet running Tasker Apps and custom Android Apps created with Flash CS6. Not for general users.

I am using Tasker and a Motion Detection App that will wake my tablet if someone walks by.  I have code in my HTML 5 web site that tests for user interaction and if there is no interaction it will reset the web site to the first page after X amount of time.

What I want it to do is also let Tasker know the user interaction information too so it can reactivate the motion detector and dim the screen if there is no user interaction.  I have looked and I cant seem to find a Tasker profile or Tasks that will monitor if the system is idle.

I have seen some web pages showing that a Web page can send an Intent message to open an App but what I want is to just send Tasker a simple message either 0 or 1.

I am using an HTML5 Kiosk browser compatible with chrome but not the Chrome Browser.

My question:
 1. Is there any way to send an HTML5 Intent message to Tasker?
 2. Or is there a better way to do this from within Tasker?
 3. Or is there an app that monitors user interaction and will send an intent message that Tasker can read?
4. Or is there a way for Flash CS6 (Android app) to send an Intent for Tasker?

I am not looking for Android code because I don't program in that language.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Tasker Network Event Server. You could send a "still alive"-message to the Tasker plugin over http with javascript, when a user clicks on a link or anywhere else on the screen inside the browser.  Tasker could dim the display if there is no click for a few minutes...
(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bidoismorgan.httpevent&hl=de)